# trying to reload the page a number of times after a form submission

Tags: javascript, web, local-storage, webflow

i use memberstack to stock the url of the avatar image of the members , but memberstack dont refresh the image after the url change , so i need to refresh the page a certain number of times to get the avatar refreshed.

I have found this code and enhanced it but i dont know why it dosent execute , seems there is an error can you find it?

```
var Webflow = Webflow || [];
Webflow.push(function() {
    $("#wf-form-avatarform").submit(function (event) {
        var timeinmilliseconds = 3000;
        var reloadCnt = window.sessionStorage.getItem( "reloadCounter") ?
            parseInt(window.sessionStorage.getItem( "reloadCounter")) + 1 :
            1;

        window.sessionStorage.setItem( "reloadCounter", reloadCnt );
        if ( reloadCnt <= 3 ){
          setTimeout(function(){ window.location.reload(true); }, timeinmilliseconds);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I can't find it... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

FIXED

now i use this script i have implemented:

```
<script> 
    if(parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem("reloadCounter")) < 3)
            reloadAfterDelay(5000);
      
    var Webflow = Webflow || [];
    Webflow.push(function() {$("#wf-form-avatarform").submit(function (event) {
                window.localStorage.setItem( "reloadCounter", '0');
                reloadAfterDelay(3000);
                });
   }); 
   
   function reloadAfterDelay(delay) 
   {
        window.localStorage.setItem( "reloadCounter", 
        parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem("reloadCounter")) + 1);
        setTimeout("location.reload(true);" , delay);
   }
</script>
```